# Resetting the Nether in a Realm in Minecraft Java Edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

Is it possible to reset the Nether in a realm?
I was wondering if it was possible to reset it in the same way they get reset in other Minecraft worlds. I have a big realm where we built everything with my friends, but since we have explored much of the nether, we were going to reset it, but since it is a Realm, we don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend:

1. Backing up your realm world
2. Downloading the backup locally - the current realm world will be downloaded and added to your single player worlds on your local PC
3. The Nether is stored in .minecraft/saves/worldname/DIM-1. Deleting this file resets the Nether, so that all player-made changes and buildings in that dimension are undone. (Minecraft Gamepedia)
4. Reset your current realm, then click "Upload world"
5. Find and select the name of the world in which you deleted the nether

Read the following sources on how to backup/restore a [Minecraft Realm World](https://www.howtogeek.com/237491/how-to-backup-and-restore-your-minecraft-realms-worlds/) and [deleting the Nether from a singleplayer world](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Nether#Technical_information):

Note: I have never used Realms nor deleted my Nether from my world. I have only done research from the above articles. Please be careful when deleting files. Always make backups. Follow these instructions at your own risk. Good Luck!